# Email windows Service status in HTML body - powershell

Tags: powershell-3.0

I am trying to email the output of windows services status in HTML
Sending the text output in email works fine, so the problem lies in this part where I am trying to convert it to HTML.

```
$servicestatusALL = Get-Content $Logfile | select-object -skip 1 
$Style = @"
<style>
BODY{font-family:Calibri;font-size:12pt;}
TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;}
TH{border-width: 1px;padding: 5px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;color:black;background-color:#0BC68D;text-align:center;}
TD{border-width: 1px;padding: 5px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;text-align:center;}
</style>
"@
$servicestatusALL | ConvertTo-Html -property 'Displayname','Status' -Head $Style | foreach {if($_ -like "*<td>Running</td>*"){$_ -replace "<tr>", "<tr bgcolor=#089437>"} elseif($_ -like "*<td>Stopped</td>*" -or "*<td>Stopping</td>*" -or "*<td>Pending</td>*" -or "*<td>Starting</td>*"){$_ -replace "<tr>", "<tr bgcolor=#C60B1C>"}  else{$_}} |out-file $reportpath

$body = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("$reportpath")
```

Sample $Logfile

```
DisplayName  Status
-----------  ------
Redis       Running
Apache2.4   Running
Appservice1 Running
Appservice2 Stopped
Appservice3 Running
Appservice4 Running
```

There is no errors but this part just returns null

> $servicestatusALL | ConvertTo-Html -property 'Displayname','Status'
> -Head $Style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I didn't understand the request, I think it is enough to change the **$servicestatusALL** variable. Instead of doing a **get-content**, I would do a **get-service**.
my proposal below:

```
$servicestatusALL = Get-Service | select displayname,status
$Style = @"
<style>
BODY{font-family:Calibri;font-size:12pt;}
TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;}
TH{border-width: 1px;padding: 5px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;color:black;background-color:#0BC68D;text-align:center;}
TD{border-width: 1px;padding: 5px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;text-align:center;}
</style>
"@
$servicestatusALL | ConvertTo-Html -property 'Displayname','Status' -Head $Style | foreach {if($_ -like "*<td>Running</td>*"){$_ -replace "<tr>", "<tr bgcolor=#089437>"} elseif($_ -like "*<td>Stopped</td>*" -or "*<td>Stopping</td>*" -or "*<td>Pending</td>*" -or "*<td>Starting</td>*"){$_ -replace "<tr>", "<tr bgcolor=#C60B1C>"}  else{$_}} |out-file $reportpath

$body = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("$reportpath")
```